# Displaying a column of associated names in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models, Listing and Invitation, associated with has_and_belongs_to_many.  I am looking at invitations through ActiveAdmin and would like to display the names of the associated listings.  I attempt this with the following code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Invitation do
  index do
    column("Listings") { |invitation| invitation.listings.each do |listing|
                          listing.name
                          end
                       }
    default_actions
  end
end
```

But nothing shows up.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you want a single column with all the listings names of the invitation. Please try the following

```
column 'listing' do |invitation|
  invitation.listings.collect(&:name).join(', ')
end
```

You might want to customize this later on and add a includes(:listings) to increase db retrieval performance.

Comment: This works!  Thanks!  Would you be able to shed light on why I can use  'each' and a block as I illustrated in the question?

Comment: You can. However You'd most probably be wanting to return a string of some sort. It all depends on your logic :) Though for a single line in a block i think the {} notation is a lot better